# Evanescent waves and "phase-matching" argument

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, reflection, waveguide

I have looked through several Classical ED approaches to introduce evanescent waves, but still can't build the connections.

1. I was told that evanescent waves are needed to satisfy boundary conditions on the interface metal-dielectric, see the slide

[image]

The argument "if and only if" is not obvious to me. Why is this the only option?

2. Trying to find an alternative way to theoretically "generate" evanescent fields, I came across the statement that [phase-matching ensures momentum conservation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/247375/physical-meaning-of-phase-matching), which made even less sense relying on (1); however, intuitively it must be true, I just can't see it. I think there might be a cross-matching of terminology in Classical ED and Non-linear Optics here though.

How can I strictly prove the necessary presence of evanescent waves, without making this logical jumps?

**Additional comment:** I found the argument [here](http://www.fulviofrisone.com/attachments/article/404/elements-of-photonics-volume-1.pdf), p.113, that since continuity should be met in space and time across the boundary, $k_i^{||}=k_r^{||}=k_t^{||}$ should take place. Otherwise, the boundary conditions can be satisfied instantaneously, but not in time. I like the semantics, but I'd rather see the mathematical prof, if it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy to understand. The condition of continuity of the tangential electric field at $z=0$ has to hold for all $x$ along the $z=0$ interface. This implies that all three x-components of $k$ have to be equal. If this were not the case, you could, e.g., satisfy the condition at $x=0$. Then with different $k_x$ and at an $x \gt 0$ you would get tangential field changed by different factors, which no longer satisfy the boundary condition. Thus you need identical $k_x$ to satisfy the boundary condition for all $x$.